# What is the correct way to implement this loop that will average values with a changing counter?

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, average, high-level

I have looked thoroughly on the internet for an answer to this question, but it seems to be too specific for an answer anywhere else. This is my last stop.

To preface, this is *not* a homework problem, but it *is* adapted from an online Coursera course, whose quiz has already passed. I got the correct answer, but it was mostly luck. Also, it is a more of a general programming question than anything related to the course, so I know for a fact that it is within my right to ask it on a public forum.

The last thing is that I'm trying to do this in MatLab; however if you have an answer that is in C++ or Python or any other high level language, that would be wonderful, as I could easily adapt those solutions to MatLab syntax.

Here it is:

I have two vectors, T and M, each with 600,000 elements/entries/integers.

T is entered as milliseconds from 1 to 600,000 in ascending order, and each element in M represents 'on' or 'off' (entered as 1 or 0 respectively) for each corresponding millisecond entry in T.  So there are random 1's and 0's in M that correspond to a particular millisecond from 1 to 600,000 in T.

I need to take, starting with the 150th millisecond of T, and in 150 element/millisecond increments from there on (inclusive), the average millisecond value of those groups of 150 but ONLY of those milliseconds whose entries are 1 in M ('on'). For example, I need to look at the first 150 milliseconds in T, see which ones have a value of 1 in M, and then average them. Then I need to do it again with entries 151 to 300 in T, then 301 to 450, etc. etc. These new averages should also be stored in a new vector. The problem is, the number of corresponding 1's in M isn't going to be the same for every group of 150 milliseconds in T. (And yes, we are trying to average the actual value of the milliseconds, so the values we are using to average and the order of the entries in T will be the same).

My attempt:

It turns out there are only 53,583 random 1's in M (out of the 600,000 entries, the rest are 0). I used a 'find' operator to extract those entries from M that are a 1 into a new vector K that has the millisecond value corresponding from T. So K looks like a bunch of random numbers in ascending order, which is just a list of all the milliseconds in T who are 'on' (assigned a 1 in M).

So K looks something like [2  5  11  27  39  40  79 ......  599,698  599,727 etc.] (all of the millisecond values who are a 1 in M).

So I have the vector K which is all of the values that I need to average in groups of 150, but the problem is that I need to go in groups of 150 based on the vector T (1 to 600,000), which means there won't always be the same number of 1's (or values in K) in every group of 150 milliseconds in T, which in turn means the number I need to divide by to get the average of each group is going to change for each group of 150. I know I need to use a loop to do the average millisecond value for every 150 entries, but how do I get the dividing number (the number of entries for each group of 150 who is assigned a 1 or 'on') to change on each iteration of the loop? Is there a way to bind T and M together so that they only use the requisite values from K whenever there is a 1 in M, and then just use a simple counter to average?

It's not a complicated problem, but it is very hard to explain. Sorry about that! I hope I explained as clearly as I could. Any help would be appreciated, although I'm sure you'll have questions first.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work OK.

```
sz = length(T);
n = sz / 150; 
K = T.*M';

t = 1;
aver = zeros(n-1,1); % Your result vector

for i = 1:150:sz-150
  aver(t) = mean(K(i:(i+150)-1));
  t = t + 1;
end
```

-Rob